# What causes a SIGILL with an ILL_ILLTRP code on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've received a crash report for my iOS application where the exception type is `SIGILL` with an exception code of `ILL_ILLTRP`, which I've never seen before.

The only information I can find about `ILL_ILLTRP` is in `signal.h`, where it says:

```c
/*
 * When the signal is SIGILL or SIGFPE, si_addr contains the address of
 * the faulting instruction.
 * When the signal is SIGSEGV or SIGBUS, si_addr contains the address of
 * the faulting memory reference. Although for x86 there are cases of SIGSEGV
 * for which si_addr cannot be determined and is NULL.
 * If the signal is SIGCHLD, the si_pid field will contain the child process ID,
 *  si_status contains the exit value or signal and
 *  si_uid contains the real user ID of the process that sent the signal.
 */

/* Values for si_code */

/* Codes for SIGILL */
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define ILL_NOOP        0       /* if only I knew... */
#endif
#define ILL_ILLOPC      1       /* [XSI] illegal opcode */
#define ILL_ILLTRP      2       /* [XSI] illegal trap */
#define ILL_PRVOPC      3       /* [XSI] privileged opcode */
#define ILL_ILLOPN      4       /* [XSI] illegal operand -NOTIMP */
#define ILL_ILLADR      5       /* [XSI] illegal addressing mode -NOTIMP */
#define ILL_PRVREG      6       /* [XSI] privileged register -NOTIMP */
#define ILL_COPROC      7       /* [XSI] coprocessor error -NOTIMP */
#define ILL_BADSTK      8       /* [XSI] internal stack error -NOTIMP */
```

On iOS (and Swift or Obj-C), what could cause an "illegal trap" to occur?

For reference, here is the stack trace for the crashing thread:

```
Incident Identifier: A450C98F-DDB4-4593-9C93-B4C17D3EB4E4
CrashReporter Key:   DB1695E0-C812-4087-9567-D4BD5D4D491C
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2019-05-26T17:01:50Z
Launch Time:     2019-05-26T17:01:37Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 12.1.2 (16C101)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGILL
Exception Codes: ILL_ILLTRP at 0x100c3343c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CocoaLumberjack                      0x0000000100c3343c CocoaLumberjack.asyncLoggingEnabled.unsafeMutableAddressor : Swift.Bool (CocoaLumberjack.swift:73)
1   XXXApp                               0x0000000100762d08 XXXApp.XXXAppNavigationContext.append(XXXApp.XXXAppNavigationPathComponent) -> () (XXXAppNavigationContext.swift:0)
2   XXXApp                               0x0000000100763a4c merged @objc XXXApp.XXXAppNavigationContext.append(XXXApp.XXXAppNavigationPathComponent) -> () + 44
3   XXXApp                               0x000000010071ae80 -[XXXAppTableViewController viewWillAppear:] (XXXAppTableViewController.m:35)
4   XXXApp                               0x0000000100708360 -[XXXAppGroupTableViewController viewWillAppear:] (XXXAppGroupTableViewController.m:83)
5   UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3224f28 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 580
6   UIKitCore                            0x00000001b322560c -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 136
7   XXXApp                               0x00000001006d3ff8 -[XXXAppTabBarViewController sendAppearanceTransitionsToViewControllers:] (XXXAppTabBarViewController.m:441)
8   XXXApp                               0x00000001006d3d88 -[XXXAppTabBarViewController scrollViewDidScroll:] (XXXAppTabBarViewController.m:426)
9   XXXApp                               0x00000001006d1458 -[XXXAppTabBarViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews] (XXXAppTabBarViewController.m:159)
10  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c8f944 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1736
11  QuartzCore                           0x000000018ac4db74 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
12  QuartzCore                           0x000000018ac52b2c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
13  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c7acc8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 544
14  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b318bd0c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1292
15  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3186400 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 232
16  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b31845d0 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 776
17  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c4a7d4 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 416
18  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c4aa90 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 584
19  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c58950 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 308
20  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c5438c +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 332
21  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c4a518 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 1860
22  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b318cb1c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2652
23  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b318d0f8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1180
24  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b318e3f8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 160
25  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b31705e8 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 220
26  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b3c8f7dc -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1376
27  QuartzCore                           0x000000018ac4db74 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
28  QuartzCore                           0x000000018ac52b2c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
29  QuartzCore                           0x000000018abb144c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336
30  QuartzCore                           0x000000018abdfd7c CA::Transaction::commit() + 604
31  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b380fa3c _afterCACommitHandler + 252
32  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001865e07cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
33  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001865db460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 408
34  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001865dba00 __CFRunLoopRun + 1260
35  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001865db1f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
36  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000188854584 GSEventRunModal + 96
37  UIKitCore                            0x00000001b37e6d40 UIApplicationMain + 208
38  XXXApp                               0x00000001006c96e4 main (main.m:16)
39  libdyld.dylib                        0x000000018609abb4 start + 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to understand what happened. I don’t have a solution, but a few ideas:

The stack trace (line 0) says the crash is in the `CocoaLumberjack` swift code at line 73, where a `Bool` `var` `asyncLoggingEnabled` should be accessed using an `unsafeMutableAddressor`.
Apparently, this is the instruction

```
public var asyncLoggingEnabled = true
```

in this code at line 73.

I believe this `var` is accessed using an `UnsafeMutablePointer` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer)).  Here, the app is

> ... responsible for handling the life cycle of any memory you work with
>   through unsafe pointers to avoid leaks or undefined behavior.

Particularly,

> Many pointer operations must only be applied to pointers with memory
>   in a specific state—you must keep track of the state of the memory you
>   are working with and understand the changes to that state that
>   different operations perform. Memory can be untyped and uninitialized,
>   bound to a type and uninitialized, or bound to a type and initialized
>   to a value. Finally, memory that was allocated previously may have
>   been deallocated, leaving existing pointers referencing unallocated
>   memory.

I believe that your app crashed because the pointer used to access `asyncLoggingEnabled` points to memory in an illegal state.
If this happens, a system trap should be executed to handle the situation, but it can only be executed if a trap handler for this type of exception has been installed. If this is not the case, an **illegal trap** (Exception Code: ILL_ILLTRP) is done that handles all not handled traps.

Probably, the memory could by chance also be in a legal state, depending on the execution history. Thus, the crash may happen or not.

To cut it short, I think this is a bug in `CocoaLumberjack`.

Comment: Thank you for going into so much detail. Your analysis makes sense. I will file a bug against CocoaLumberjack.